# Filter array of objects by multiple strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

Trying to wrap my brain around how I should tackle filtering an array of objects and only returning results that satisfy **all of the tags**.

The tags could be any of the fields - `fname`/`lname`/`email`/`position`/`etc`

```
let search_tags = ['CEO', 'Steven'];

let contacts = [
  { fname: 'Steve', lname: 'Johnson', email: 'user@domain.com', position: 'CEO' },
  { fname: 'James', lname: 'Laurence', email: 'boss@domain.com', position: 'CFO' }
]

let results = contacts.filter((contact) => {
  if (search_tags.includes(contact.fname) || 
      search_tags.includes(contact.lname) ... ) {
    return contact;
  }
}
```

I shortened a bit of the code for brevity and obviously this solution will return contacts that match **any** `search_tag` but... I need to only return results that satisfy **every** `search_tag`.

It's been a long day and I have no one to talk this through so I'm hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction or give me that *ah-ha!* moment I'm hoping for :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use && rather than ||

Comment: If you are just looking to be pointed in the right direction: turn search_tags into a `Set` object then for each object in contacts, create a set of the field values, then do a set intersection or symmetric difference. Let us know if you need help doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return one that matched every search tag you'd want to use `&&` instead of `||` but that still leaves you with a bunch of verbose and duplicated code

Instead of operating directly on the contact Object, you can use Object.values() https://mdn.io/objectvalues which would give you an array of `['steve', 'johnson', 'user@domain]`... etc.

Then you could in your filter:

```
contacts.filter((contact) => {
    const contactValues = Object.values(contact);
    // Return the search item if at least one item matches
    // Would return true if at least one item matches
    return contactValues.some(value => search_tags.includes(value));
    // return true only if all search tags match
    return contactValues.every(value => search_tags.includes(value));
}
```

`Object.values` is quite a new feature, so if you don't have it available in babel, then you can use `Object.keys` and grab the value using `contact[someKey]`

Comment: Your second return will never be hit.

Comment: @Geuis I think it is included as a "template" and OP is expected to keep one of the two

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can be combined with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to construct an `Array` of `matches` consisting solely of `contact` `Objects` that contain a matching `value` for every `element` in `search_tags`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Search Tags.
const search_tags = ['CEO', 'Steven']

// Contacts.
let contacts = [
  { fname: 'Steven', lname: 'Johnson', email: 'user@domain.com', position: 'CEO' },
  { fname: 'James', lname: 'Laurence', email: 'boss@domain.com', position: 'CFO' }
]

// Matches.
const matches = contacts.filter((contact) => search_tags.every((tag) => Object.values(contact).includes(tag)))

// Log.
console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6:

```
function filterIt(arr, searchKeys) {
  return arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => searchKeys.includes(obj[key])));
}
```